# My totalsumMethod will not sum the total of an array

Tags: java, arrays

The program asked the user how many inches of rainfall per month and the user inputs the amount 12 times since their are 12 months in a year and after they input the number of inches of rainfall for 12 months, its suppose to sum up all of the inputs:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class RainFall {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int MONTHS=12;
        double rainfall[]=new double[MONTHS];

        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("The total rainfal is "+totalRainFall(rainfall));


    }

    public static double totalRainFall(double rainfall[]){
        int total=0;

        int MONTHS=12;

        for(int index=0; index<MONTHS;index++){

            Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the total rainfall");

            rainfall[index]=keyboard.nextDouble();
            total+=rainfall[MONTHS];

         }


        return total;
    }


    }
```

> ```
> Enter the total rainfall
> 89.9
> Exception in thread "main" 
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
>    at RainFall.totalRainFall(RainFall.java:27)
>    at RainFall.main(RainFall.java:11)
> ```

But now I get an out of bound error when I compile and executed the code even though their are no compilation errors as shown right above this comment.

I have executed this code before with no issue, but now I am getting errors. I started getting errors when I replace my for loop with a while loop , and then put my original forloop back.

Comment: There is no index 12 on an array of size 12. You seem to know that the array is `0` based, so where would item 12 come from?

Comment: Yes, make it `total+=rainfall[index];` and it will work.